# Хранение истории изменений в единой таблице

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Хочу вести учет истории изменений, *по гуглив* наткнулся на [**Метод единой таблицы аудита**](http://rsdn.org/article/db/dbhistory.xml),

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.History (
  TableName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
 ,ColumnName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
 ,RowId INT NOT NULL
 ,ActionType VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
 ,Author INT NOT NULL
 ,StartDate DATETIME NOT NULL
 ,EndDate DATETIME NOT NULL
 ,IsCurrent BIT NOT NULL
)
GO
```

В данной таблице у меня не хватает как минимум двух полей, предыдущее(*PreviousValue*) и текущее значение(*CurrentValue*), загвоздка в том что значения будут разных типов, и я не знаю как правильней поступить.

Для каждого типа значения создать отдельную пару, т.е. PreviousInt, CurrentInt, PreviousDecimal CurrentDecimal, и т.д.

Или же в приложении, перед записью приводить значение к строке и тогда достаточно будет двух колонок: предыдущее и текущее.

Подскажите как лучше поступить, какие трудности могут возникнуть в том или ином случае?

Answer (score 3):

Для хранения простых типов, можно все переводить в строковый тип. Но если вы хотите хранить все предыдущие значения в своих типах. То можно в таблицу с важными данными добавить два столбца "start_date", "end_date".

Например:

```
CREATE TABLE agreements (
    id integer,
    start_date date,
    end_date date,
    created_user_id integer,
    updated_user_id integer,
    number string,
    org_name string,
    agreement_date date,
);
```

Пользователь `12` завел договор первого января:

```
{'1', '2018-01-01', null, 12, 12, 'XX-001', 'Копыта и рога', '2018-01-01'}
```

Второго января выяснилось что название указано неверно,
и пользователь `13` меняет название, в старой записи заполняется `end_date` и заводиться новая строка:

```
{'1', '2018-01-01', '2018-01-02', 12, 12, 'XX-001', 'Копыта и рога', '2018-01-01'}
{'1', '2018-01-02', null,         12, 13, 'XX-001', 'Рога и копыта', '2018-01-01'}
```

Данные на текущий момент можно получить так:

```
select *
from agreements
where start_date <= GETDATE()
and isNull(end_date,GETDATE()) >= GETDATE()
```

Что бы получить информацию за другую дату, можно заменить все GETDATE(), на нее.
Например данные на `2018-01-01`:

```
select *
from agreements
where start_date <= '2018-01-01'
and isNull(end_date,'2018-01-01') >= '2018-01-01'
```

Отсортировав строки по start_date для одного id получаем хронологию изменений:

```
select *
from agreements
where id = 1
order by start_date;
```

Comment: такой вариант тоже рассматривался, и если быть честным то он мне нравится, но есть некоторые вопросы: историю хранить в таблице с оригинальными данными или же лучше вынести в отдельную таблицу, если в одной то тогда не хватает признака актуальности, а как быть с ключом, ведь на него могут ссылаться другие таблицы?

Comment: @Bald, Не надо выносить в отдельную таблицу. Этот очень удобный метод. У актуальных данных `end_date` всегда `null`. Ключ `id`, Уникальный ключ `id, start_date, end_date`. Не актуальные изменения за предыдущий год при необходимости можно удалить не сложным запросом `delete from agreements where end_date is not null and end_date < '2018-01-01';`

Comment: да Вы правы, надо попробовать...

Comment: @Максим думаю для актуальных данных нужен флаг, что-то типа isActive и индекс по нему, тогда и проблем с выборкой не будет.

Comment: @NickProskuryakov актуальные данные можно действительно получить через `EndDate is null`, `IsActive` позволить получить тоже самое, только быстрее?

Comment: @Bald думаю да, индекс по дате не лучший вариант, особенно с учетом null

Comment: @NickProskuryakov, в данной ситуации `isActive` абсолютно бесполезное поле (избыточная информация). Так может быть что действительно понадобиться атрибут `active`, а он занят не понятно чем. Попробуйте придумать хоть один полезный пример, в котором поле `isActive` выигрывает перед `end_date is null`.

Comment: @Максим именование полей личное дело каждого, это всего лишь частный пример. Теперь подробнее о полях и фильтрации: создаем простую табличку с полями id, data, isActive заполняем 500к записями, часть из них у нас будет с датой is null и isActive =1, делаем индексы на поля и видим что индекс по дате не используетсяб при фильтрации по ней, в отличае от фильриации по флагу. Смотрим статистику чтений, и видим что для фильтрации по дате сделано в два раза больше логических чтений чем по флагу.

Comment: @NickProskuryakov, нет тут с индексами никакого преимущества. Делать индекс по одному полю `end_date` никто не будет, это нигде не понадобиться. Зато вы создаете ситуацию, когда `isActive = 1`, а `end_date is not null`, без этого поля такую ошибку допустить не получиться. По вашему получается, что стоит еще добавить поля `isArhived` для `end_date is not null`, `isUpdated` для строк которые были изменены, `isAdminCreated` для строк которые созданы администраторами. Не стоит давать вредные советы.

Comment: @Максим я не предлагал делать индекс по одному полю это раз, два вы совершенно не поняли того что я написал. Не нужно вводить людей в заблуждение. И давайте закроем тему.

Answer (score 2):

Решая подобную задачу, мы сделали отдельную схему, к примеру LogSchema, где делали лог-таблицу для каждой из отслеживаемых. 
Таким образом, решалось несколько проблем:

1. У нас не было одной огромной таблицы
2. У нас не было проблем с хранением данных (дилемма с типами полей и способом)
3. С таблицами было достаточно просто работать, когда требовались исторические данные.

Хочу подметить еще тот момент, нам было просто удобно так сделать. Вам же рекомендую посмотреть, как Вам удобнее.

Касаемо хранения вашего значения - в теории можно попробовать `sql_variant` (а лучше - не стоит, уж проблем будет с ним просто куча, можно почитать [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039455/should-i-use-sql-variant-data-type) ) или же `nvarchar`, как, теоретически общий для всего.

Но, используя "неродной" тип, Вы, в теории, можете словить ошибку приведения, ошибку точности и т.п. - а оно Вам нужно?

Comment: *У нас не было проблем с хранением данных (дилемма с типами полей и способом)* - т.е. по факту у вас, применяется метод таблиц двойников?!

Comment: @Bald, да, надо было сразу написать. Способ, тот еще, конечно, но там это можно было себе позволить. Ну и рост данных не большой, т.к. изменять там требовалось редко.